# How To Return mysqli_fetch_assoc in While Loop As Variable in PHP Function?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP function :

```
function userParent($Username)
{
global $con;
$Result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = '$Username' LIMIT 10");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result);
return $row; 
}
```

that function should give me 10 rows in array, but why I just have a value in array? I tried to test that codes outside function bracket and try to add WHILE loop like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

and it works. I got my 10 rows in array format. but it prints the result to the screen. how to make it as variable so it can be returned in function?

thanks.

UPDATE : according to Phil's answer, now here's my complete code :

```
<?php
function userParent(mysqli $con, $username) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = ? LIMIT 10');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    return $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$DbServer = 'localhost';
$DbUser = 'username';
$DbPassword = 'password';
$DbName = 'dbname';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName);

$arrayParent = userParent($mysqli, 'root');
print_r($arrayParent);

?>
```

but I got this error message :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/myhome/public_html/test.php on line 6

Comment: could you please tell me why what's wrong with global?

Comment: It`s a "Bad practice".

Comment: @CORRUPT : then should I put this row : $con = mysqli_connect($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName); on each function I have?

Comment: @RobertHanson http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: @RobertHanson Don't make such functions first of all

Comment: @RobertHanson No, you simply pass the `mysqli` instance as an argument where it is required

Comment: Why are the queries different in your two examples?

Comment: @Phil : just updated. now both have same queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead

```
function userParent(mysqli $con, $username) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = ? LIMIT 10');
    if ($stmt === false) {
        throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    return $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Then call it like this

```
$parents = userParent($mysqli, 'some username');
```

Read these in case you're not aware of prepared statements and parameter binding

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

### Update

Apparently (undocumented), the `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` method is only available when using the `mysqlnd` driver. If you cannot use this driver, try this alternative

```
function userParent(mysqli $con, $username) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = ? LIMIT 10');
    if ($stmt === false) {
        throw new Exception($con->error, $con->errno);
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $parent = null;
    $parents = array();
    $stmt->bind_result($parent);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $parents[] = $parent;
    }
    return $parents;
}
```

Comment: Provide him a procedural way, as he is using `mysqli_()`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why? It makes no difference.

Comment: Let's see if he understands this

Comment: @Mr.Alien The functions and methods not only do the same thing but are referenced on the very same manual pages. You don't need to clutter up the code with global, `mysqli_` prefixed functions when the instance methods are available

Comment: I can understand that but he won't get it that what's going on in the above code, am not saying the answer is incorrect, it's just he wont get this, also the `?` in the query part, better provide a solution which he will understand else he will simply copy paste the stuff and use it without understanding

Comment: @Mr.Alien : don't worry.. I understand about OOP style too. what I didn't know was where to put $con if I'm using procedural way. I did it by using global. but you said it's not good thing to do. But I think I will go with Phil's way...

Comment: @Phil : I tried to use your way like this : 

$mysqli = new mysqli($DbServer, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbName);
$arrayParent = userParent(mysqli $mysqli, 'johndoe');
print_r($arrayParent);

and gives me this result :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/rhanson2/public_html/test.php on line 17

Comment: You don't use [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) when calling a function, they are only for the function signature. I've provided a usage example

Comment: @Phil : Hi Phil, I just updated my post because I have a new error message. please see above. thank you.

Comment: @RobertHanson I've updated my answer. This is why I **always** recommend PDO over MySQLi

Comment: @Phil : Now, I got this : Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/myhome/public_html/test.php on line 4

Comment: @Phil : is there something wrong with my server's? should I change something on the server first to make this code run smoothly?

Comment: @RobertHanson Sounds like the `prepare()` failed. I've updated my answer with some error checking

Comment: @Phil : works like a charm bro!! thanks a million! I really appreciate it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `return`:

```
function userParent(mysqli &$dbms, $username){
    // You need to "escape" strings, which you would use in direct queries.
    // OR BETTER: use mysqli prepared statements with parameter binding.
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbms, $username);

    $result = mysqli_query($dbms, "SELECT Username FROM Family WHERE Parent = '$username' LIMIT 10");

    // Create temporary array for resultset:
    $buffer = array();

    // Fetch data to temporary buffer:
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $buffer[] = $row;
    }

    // Free result set:
    $result->free();

    // Return buffer to global scope:
    return $buffer;
}

$users = userParent($con, 'John');

var_dump($users);
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the `mysqli` instance by reference. Objects are implicitly passed by reference

Comment: **@Phil**, it might be, but I'm don't trust it. Just prefer a `C++` way. Still, I know, that `PHP`-references are not `C++` pointers. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Might want to watch out for parameters with apostrophes in them, eg `O'Neil`